# Typescript no compatible call signatures error with union types

Tags: typescript

I have 2 classes, both of them having a function with the same name, but they expect a different argument object:

```
class C1 {
    public f: (params: { a: string }) => {
    }
}
class C2 {
    public f: (params: { b: string }) => {
    }
}
```

Then I have a function that gets `C1 | C2`, and I try to call the function with a config object that has all the properties for *both* `C1.f` and `C2.f`.

But this gives an error:

```
const fx = (c: C1 | C2) => {
    const params = { a: "a", b: "b" };
    c.f(params);
}
```

The best solution I could come up with is to add an `instanceof` to implicitly cast `c` to `C1` and `C2` and call the function:

```
if (c instanceof C1) {
    c.f(params);
} else {
    c.f(params);
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20C1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20f%3A%20(params%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20C2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20f%3A%20(params%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fx%20%3D%20(c%3A%20C1%20%7C%20C2)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20params%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20b%3A%20%22b%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(c%20instanceof%20C1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.f(params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.f(params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c.f(params)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Is there a simpler way to call the common function without typecasting?

Comment: If the classes C1 and C2 are your own classes you can specify an interface with f method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Ensure that when f is called, the params must have both `a` and `b`:
interface IC {
    f: (params: { a: string } & { b: string }) => {};
};
//Here it is fine to assume that the params contain a:
class C1 implements IC {
    public f: (params: { a: string }) => {
    }
}
//Here it is fine to assume that the params contain `b`:
class C2 implements IC {
    public f: (params: { b: string }) => {
    }
}
const fx = (c: IC) => {
    const params = { a: "a", b: "b" };
    c.f(params);
}
```

Comment: Seems good, compiles in strict mode and warns if any of the properties are missing. Thanks!

Comment: Just made an edit to use `&` instead of `|`.  Otherwise when you try to use the params inside the function you couldn't be sure that either `a` or `b` exist.

Comment: Yeah, I was typing a comment that it does not work when you made your edit:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const fx = (c: C1 | C2) => {
    const params = { a: "a", b: "b" };
    type T = (params: { a: string; b: string; }) => void;
    let f_: T = c.f;
    f_(params);
}
```