# Assign Typescript type in switch statement

Tags: typescript, d3.js

Try to write a generic function function to return `d3 scale`. but getting the following error as it is reading the wrong type after the `switch` statement.

```
import * as D3Scale from 'd3-scale';

enum scaleIdentites {
linear,
time,
}

interface ScaleProps {
    scaleIdentity: scaleIdentites;
    range: number[];
    domain: number[];
}

export const scale = ({ scaleIdentity, domain }: ScaleProps) => {
    let scaleFunction: D3Scale.ScaleLinear<number, number> | D3Scale.ScaleTime<number, number>;
    switch (scaleIdentity) {
        case scaleIdentites.linear:
            scaleFunction = D3Scale.scaleLinear();
            scaleFunction.domain([1, 2]); // correctly reads the correct type and doesnt error.
            break;
        case scaleIdentites.time:
            scaleFunction = D3Scale.scaleTime();
            scaleFunction.domain([1, 2]); // correctly reads the correct type and doesnt error.
            break;
        default: {
            throw new Error(`Unknow scale ${scaleIdentity}`);
        }
    }
    if (domain) {
        scaleFunction.domain(domain); // error as saying should have 0 parameters.
    }
};
```

When inside the `case` block it correctly allows me to use a parameter in `domain`. Outside it errors.

Comment: maybe not related to the error but `scaleTime` uses `Date` as domain elements. Or are you interested in the first ms after 1970-01-01. You assign the result of a lambda that does not return a result.

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for the heads up. Tried changing to `domain: Array<number | Date>;` but still get the same error. It seems like `typescript` keeps linking back to `domain(): number[]` within the `d3-scale` types. When it should see it can have `domain(domain: Array<number | { valueOf(): number }>): this;` also. Ive basically had to duplicate code in the respective `case` statements

Comment: What does the generated JavaScript look like?

Comment: It wont compile. `src/app/Components/D3/utils/scale.ts:55:5 - error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
`

Comment: What is the code at line `scale.ts::55`?

Comment: `scaleFunction.domain(domain);` this line within the `if` statement at the end. As far as I understand `d3` allows you to call `.domain()` to get the current domain, or `.domain([0,1]` to set the domain. However `typescript` only recognises the first one and therefore errors saying `Expected 0 arguments`. As you can see in the `case` statements it is working as expected.

Comment: What is the type of `scaleFunction` outside the case? Which `domain()` does it thinks you want to use?

Comment: I set `scaleFunction` to be either type `D3Scale.ScaleLinear | D3Scale.ScaleTime` and then set it within the `switch`. Both `scaleLinear` & `scaleTime` have `domain` attached as methods. It then thinks it is trying to use the `domain` that accepts 0 parameters

Comment: Next time please include the import statement in your code sample to save answerers the trouble of reverse-engineering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the 1-argument overloads of `ScaleLinear.domain` and `ScaleTime.domain` have different parameter types (even though `number[]` is assignable to both), and when you have a union type, [TypeScript keeps only the call signatures with identical parameter types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294#issuecomment-190335544), which in this case is only the 0-argument overload.

In this example, it doesn't seem too bad to me to duplicate the `if (domain) { scaleFunction.domain(domain); }` logic in both cases.  If you really want to avoid duplicating that `if` statement, you can do:

```
export const scale = ({ scaleIdentity, domain }: ScaleProps) => {
    let scaleFunction: D3Scale.ScaleLinear<number, number> | D3Scale.ScaleTime<number, number>;
    let setDomain: (domain: number[]) => void;
    switch (scaleIdentity) {
        case scaleIdentites.linear:
            const linearFunction = scaleFunction = D3Scale.scaleLinear();
            setDomain = (domain) => linearFunction.domain(domain);
            break;
        case scaleIdentites.time:
            const timeFunction = scaleFunction = D3Scale.scaleTime();
            setDomain = (domain) => timeFunction.domain(domain);
            break;
        default: {
            throw new Error(`Unknow scale ${scaleIdentity}`);
        }
    }
    if (domain) {
        setDomain(domain);
    }
};
```

Note the use of a new `const` variable because narrowing of `let` variables doesn't propagate into callbacks.

[Typescript no compatible call signatures error with union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461573/typescript-no-compatible-call-signatures-error-with-union-types) is very similar, but not similar enough for me to vote this as a duplicate.

Comment: thanks. I stuck with the duplicate `if` statements in the end but appreciate the explanation very much.